# Mysterious String to double conversion

Tags: c#

I am tying to convert a string to double in C#, wherein i face a situation,

String of value `"6,,"` gets converted to double whereas the string `"6++"` or a number with successive chars throws an error which is understandable.

Please clarify why the first string gets converted?

Comment: Please post _how_ you are converting to double, as well as what culture you're using.

Comment: i am just using Convert.ToDouble("6,,")

Comment: @DStanley Culture is default as per in the Editer.

Comment: What is your default culture?  `en-US`?

Comment: @DStanley Yes it is en-US

Comment: Just look here what and why gets parsed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx

Comment: @m0s thats helpful indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `,` is the thousands separator for the invariant culture, the parser just ignores them *before* the decimal point.  You can also parse `"6,4,55.23"` and it yields `6455.23`.

Trying to parse a number with a comma *after* the decimal point, however, results in an error.

In the documentation doe [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the following rules are given (paraphrased):

> *[ws][sign][integral-digits[,]]integral-digits[.[fractional-digits]][E[sign]exponential-digits][ws]*
>
> - Runs of integral-digits can be partitioned by a group-separator symbol. For example, in some cultures a comma (,) separates groups of thousands

So there's no requirement that the thousands separator have three digits after it (or between consecutive separators)

Comment: then how does 6,, is stored

Comment: that really clarified my doubts

Answer (score 3):

The comma is used as a thousands separator in some cultures, so it's acceptable for it to be present in a numeric string. The same cannot be said for a plus sign.

To clarify, "+6" would be valid, since you can represent a positive number explicitly with the plus sign. However, "6+" is not a recognised numeric format in any culture that I am aware of. Similarly, while "6," could be considered valid, ",6" probably isn't unless you specifically use a culture where the comma is a decimal separator.